# printf("%s") not working properly

Tags: c, string, printf

So i have this big code ( so wont be able to put the entire thing here).
But at a point i have this.

```
while(ptr1!=NULL)
{
printf("%sab ",ptr1->name);
puts(ptr1->name);
ptr1=ptr1->next;
}
```

Now my ptr1 point to a an entry of the array of a structure( each entry being a linked list), and the structure was populated from a file.

Now in this loop it prints

```
FIRSTab FIRST
SECONDab SECOND
THIRD
```

Now why doesnt my THIRD GETS PRINTED TWICE?

Also if i do

```
printf(" %s",ptr1->name); // i.e. one space before %s
```

I get

```
THIRDD
```

Putting 2 spaces before %s gives me

```
THIRDRD
```

3 spaces gives

```
THIRDIRD
```

And so on.

Also if i try to do strcmp(ptr1->name,"THIRD") i wont get the correct comparison for THIRD.
Why??

Here is how i populated my structure.

```
// G is the structure, fp is passed as argument to function.
//THe file format is like this.
//FIRST SECOND THIRD
//NINE ELEVEN 
//FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN
// and so on.
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
char string[100];
while(!feof(fp))
{
if(fgets(string,100,fp))
{
G[i].index=i;
k=0;j=0;
//\\printf("%d",i);
//puts(string);
node *new=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
new->next=NULL;
G[i].ptr=new;
node* pointer;
pointer=G[i].ptr;
while(string[j]!='\n')
{
    if(string[j]==' ')
    {
    pointer->name[k]='\0';

    k=0;
        node *new=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        new->next=NULL;
        pointer->next=new;
        pointer=pointer->next;
        j++;
    }
    else
    {   
    pointer->name[k++]=string[j]; 
    j++; 
    }
}
pointer->name[k]='\0';
i++;
}
```

Comment: How do you obtain `THIRD` ? **Is it 0-terminated** ?

Comment: Are you sure that `ptr1->name` is terminated with a `'\0'`?

Comment: This is not the real code. Please give us the real code.

Comment: You could have fishy chars in that string. Try redirecting your output to a file, and open it with a hex editor to see exactly what.

Comment: Are `ptr` and `ptr1` both in the actual code?

Comment: @larsmans its ptr1 only. sorry.. edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third string probably contains the characters `THIRD` followed by `\r` (carriage return). Why it contains this can only be determined by knowing the contents of the file and how your read it.

It is likely that you are either working on a system that uses a single newline character as a line terminator (but the file you are opening comes from a system that uses a carriage return and newline pair) or that the file pointer that you were passed (`fp`) was opened in binary mode.

If you can't change the file pointer to be opened in text mode then a quick fix *might* be to change this condition `while(string[j]!='\n')` to `while(string[j]!='\n' && string[j] != '\r')`, although you might want a more robust solution that handles multiple whitespace characters.

Comment: @Kraken: That's entirely up to you.

Comment: open the file in text mode: `fopen("whatever", "r")`; note `"r"`, not `"rb"`.

Comment: fp is `fp=fopen("file.txt","r");`

Comment: @CharlesBailey thanks it works now. 
ANyway, i still done get the problem? whydid not '\n' work?

Comment: @Kraken: What OS is your program running on and where did you get your text file from?

Comment: @CharlesBailey ubuntu 10.10 .  and i wrote the file manually.

Comment: @CharlesBailey i typed the whole file.. using a text editor of course.

Comment: @CharlesBailey but i guess , i wrote the file on windows 7 and then i worked on Ubuntu.

Comment: @CharlesBailey if on ubuntu, the gedit, and if on windows then notepad++.

Comment: @Kraken: If you wrote the file on windows and then transfered it onto an Ubuntu system then, unless you were using a really old fashioned ASCII ftp transfer, it is likely that the file still contains windows line endings after the transfer. Many windows editors allow you to override the default line ending conventions used when saving a file. Otherwise you would need to use a tool such as `dos2unix` to convert the line endings.

Comment: @CharlesBailey thanks a lot, you have been of utmost help! :)